# Blazor WebAssembly can't read environment variables or find files when running in Docker

Tags: docker, mono, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor webassembly project which I have dockerized and I'm trying to read environment variables set in the container on startup.
If I do the following I am able to run a shell in the container and echo the variable.

```
docker run -e DEBUG=false --name blazortest dockerizedclientsideblazor
```

However if I try to read the environment variable in the application using this command.

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DEBUG")
```

It returns as null and it's the same for trying to read mounted files.
Can explain to me why I'm experiencing this?

My Dockerfile looks like this.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN ls -la ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output

FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/web
COPY --from=build-env /app/output/wwwroot .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80 443
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming back to this question with my own answer.

Trying to retrieve the value of environment variables on the server(in this case a container) won't work since the code is being being downloaded and run on the client.

So the environment variables set on the server will not be present on the client side.

The solution would be to use appsettings instead.

Answer (score 4):

For dotnet web api's environment variables can be read like that. For blazor webassembly, this is not really possible because the client code "lives in the browser" and in your case nginx is "kind of" the client code server (simplified).

There are multiple ways to make it happen, but my favourite and (in my opinion) most suitable solution is by `executing a shell script that reads the environment variable on container startup and literally replaces` a value/values in the appsettings.json file.

So add a .sh with something like this (where does not really matter but most easy is to use it in the same location as the appsettings.json file):

```
#!/bin/sh

local_var=$(printenv "THE_DOCKER_ENV_VAR")
echo "CORE_API_BASE_ADDRESS is: $local_var"

sed -i "s|THE_DOCKER_ENV_VAR_PLACEHOLDER|${local_var}|g" appsettings.json
echo "replaced value 'THE_DOCKER_ENV_VAR' in appsettings.json with ${local_var}"
```

Then you need to make sure that this shell command is executed in the Dockerfile by adding this to the end of the Dockerfile (my entire Dockerfile is present at the end of this post):

```
# Copy the shell script
COPY ./relative/path/regarding/dockerfile/dockerrun.sh /usr/share/nginx/html/
# Set the execution permission
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/nginx/html/dockerrun.sh

# Execute the script on container startup
CMD /usr/share/nginx/html/dockerrun.sh && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

In the appsettings you need to put some kind of placeholder that will be replaced. In this case the placeholder is THE_DOCKER_ENV_VAR_PLACEHOLDER:

```
{
    "SomeVariable": "THE_DOCKER_ENV_VAR_PLACEHOLDER"
}
```

Now when you run your container and (in this case) provide the THE_DOCKER_ENV_VAR_PLACEHOLDER environment variable in your docker container, it will be replaced in the appsettings with the placeholder and you can start up different containers with different environment settings.

**OPTIONAL BUT MIGHT BE FOR YOU A GOOD CHOICE**
This scenario will make your appsettings.json more like a placeholder file. You can write an intermediate step to create the appsettings.json inside the shell script so that you can also use the appsettings.json for e.g. local development in Visual Studio or if you want to .gitignore the file.

**NOTE:** Only using CMD/ENTRYPOINT for calling the shell script will result in the container being shutdown after the shell script is executed. After the shell command is executed, we also want to start nginx.

Comment: A very nice solution. I used this with one refinement - nginx has a folder on the root /docker-entrypoint.d Any scripts in this folder will be executed on startup.
Adding the following to your dockerfile will ensure the script is run on container start. 
`COPY replace-appsettings-from-env.sh /docker-entrypoint.d/` Set script name accordingly, update path to appsettings, ensure new lines are unix _LF_ and not _CRLF_

Answer (score 2):

In fact you can specify and environment variable even if executed on client side.

Multiple options :

- Using Nginx? Add the header ‘blazer-environment’ in nginx.conf
- Using web.config? See msdn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/environments
- Want to determine it in code (startup), see same link as above

Answer (score 0):

> It returns as null and it's the same for trying to read mounted files.

Yes. Your WebAssembly app does not run in that container, it runs in the Browser of the end users.

You could read the variable and those files from a Service running on nginx.